# How to convert this SQL into laravel query builder with eloquent?

Tags: laravel

How to convert this SQL to Laravel query builder using eloquent? I want to display categories table on my datatable with count(questions) on it.

```
SELECT questions.categories_id, count(questions.categories_id) as pertanyaan, categories.name as cat_name
    FROM questions, categories
    WHERE questions.categories_id=categories.id
    GROUP BY questions.categories_id
```

Comment: try something like this   select('questions.categories_id', 'count(questions.categories_id) as pertanyaan', 'categories.name as cat_name')->join('categories','categories.id','=','questions.categories_id')->groupBy('questions.categories_id');

Answer (score -1):

```
Question::join('categories','categories.id','=','questions.categories_id')
       ->groupBy('questions.categories_id')
       ->select(
             'questions.categories_id',
             'categories.name as cat_name',
             DB::raw('COUNT(questions.categories_id)')
        );
```